# Transfer Census badge to different Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, badges, survey, survey-2019

I took the developer survey from a link on https://dba.stackexchange.com.

So the message displayed to me was

> "You are eligible for the Census badge. Please log into your Database
>   Administrators Stack Exchange account or create an account to earn
>   your badge."

But I would love to have the census badge on my Stack Overflow account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a "View other eligible sites" button. Using it I was able to get the badge on my SO account. Yeah!!

You can get the badge on any of the following sites: Ask Ubuntu, Code Review, Cross Validated, Information security, Server fault, Stack Overflow, Super User.

[image]

**You cannot transfer the Census badge after accepting it.** Right before you accept it, make a choice.

[Didn't notice the button in a hurry. Posting the answer as it might be useful for the community.]

Comment: How do you know you can't transfer it after accepting it? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Good question! 1) Documentation doesn't state "You can do so". 2) No where there is a button/link that allows to do so. 

This case is a good example of fallacy. But I'll be happy if I get proved wrong.